# Arquitetura Limpa e Arquitetura Cebola, são a mesma coisa?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Tenho dúvida se Arquitetura de cebola é a mesma Arquitetura Limpa ?
Porque me parece num primeiro momento que suas estruturas e conceitos são iguais, dai a minha dúvida.

[image: A imagem mostra os 2 tipos de arquitetura, Cebola e Limpa]

Comment: confesso que em todos os meus anos trabalhando em TI nunca havia ouvido o termo "arquitetura cebola" :D

Answer (score -1):

A arquitetura limpa é um conjunto de especificações criadas a partir de quatro grandes arquiteturas: "onion architeture", "ports and adapters" (hexagonal), "data, context and interaction" (DCI), "entity-control-boundary" (BCE).

Onion architeture é a arquitetura cebola, que você cita.

De forma mais simples, eu diria que a arquitetura limpa não guia tanto as camadas, não restringe tanto, só exige algumas especificações, como a regra de dependência, que é a regra mais forte da arquitetura limpa. As outras arquiteturas citadas, são mais como uma forma especifica de implementar seu design de projeto.

Por exemplo, a arquitetura de portas e adaptadores tem como caracteristica ter as abstrações de dados e regras de negócios criticas na cerne, os use cases numa camada mais externa, e em uma camada ainda mais externa portas e adaptadores.

Portas: entradas para web, drivers de banco de dados e etc (entrada para Web via http com Express, por exemplo)

Adaptadores: para utilizar os frameworks e drivers nas nossas portas (controller Express, por exemplo, seria utilizado para adaptar nossa entrada para Web plugando em nossa aplicação desacoplada).

A arquitetura limpa em si não vai te definir esse nível de implementação, e sim especificações mais amplas para construir software reutilizável, com manutenção mais simples, regras de negócio bem definidas, e componentes facilmente testáveis.